# Need to know how to set up WiFi for FireHD 7 on hardwired iMAC desktop

Tags: imac

Got a Fire HD 7 for christmas present. My iMac desktop & printer is wired via ethernet into a Motorola SURFboard eXtreme Wireless Cable Modem & Gigabit Router (3 products in 1 device) My question is HOW do I set up Aiport(WiFi) on  my "stuff" so I can use the Kindle in other places in my apartment using wireless????and still be hardwired for desktop & printer??

Comment: There are multiple answers to this question, however the best is turn off wifi in the Motorola and use a cable to connect the Airport to the motorola.

Comment: the wi fi is not on in the motorola,,,,,so are you recommending I get an Airport Base Station & connect it via ether on the Motorola modem??

Comment: model is a SBG6580-G228

Answer (score 1):

If you have working internet over ethernet into your iMac then all you need to do is to switch on Internet Sharing from the System Settings app and presumably your Fire HD will be able to connect to that (I don't have a Fire HD so cannot explain that end of it).

Check out http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13855

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use the wifi broadcast by the SurfBoard as well as the wired Ethernet ports to your iMac and printer since the SurfBoard is a combination modem/router with wifi. Check your documentation for the SurfBoard for configuring the wifi portion of its services, follow the instructions and connect the FireHD to the wifi network you created.

Comment: thats what I thought...I will have to call Motorolla.......my ISP said I don't have the Wi-Fi purchased on my cable........I don't think it would make a difference......internet is internet

Comment: Everything I'm finding on that model number indicates it has dual-band wifi built in. Whoever you talked to at your ISP is clueless. You can get the documentation for your SurfBoard at http://www.surfboard.com/quick-start-guides/

Comment: I have it but I am going to call Motorolla  & have them walk me thru the steps to see if it will work......I am finding most of the techs ARE clueless....LOL....everything is written for PC and not for the MAC  :(

Comment: Douggro: the start guide is written for PC...I have already tried the B & C (wizard guide) off the quick start.....They did not work

Comment: it says in the guide for option A - Note: The steps for setting up a wireless network may differ slightly depending on the operating system installed on your computer. The following steps apply to Windows® 7."

Comment: Download the User Guide (same page as the link I posted), and follow the "Setting Up a Wireless Connection"  directions using the Quick Start Wizard. This uses a standard web browser like Safari to access the router configuration and set up the wifi network.